# Graph Toolkit - mgt-picker and mgt-channel-picker - Clear the selected value

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

Once user select the channel or value in mgt-channel-picker or mgt-picker, there is no way to clean the selected value on any event using javascript.

I can ofcourse target the 'X' icon and click on it using Javascript, but will be good if this can be handle with graph toolkit. Is there any way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mgt-picker you can set the value of the selected-value attribute or the selectedValue property of the element:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    const picker = document.querySelector('mgt-picker');
    picker.selectedValue = "";
    console.log('clear selection');
});
```

For mgt-teams-channel-picker this is a gap in our current implementation. Could you please raise an issue on the repo to track this?

Comment: I tried above solution, this works only for the first time. After first time, it internally clears the selected value but not from the dropdown. Also As i understand, clearing of teams channel picker will be available from version 4.0.0, could you please confirm.

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: cpould you also please update me on this : I tried above solution, this works only for the first time. After first time, it internally clears the selected value but not from the dropdown